# Matplotlib buffer issue when using bbox_inches = 'tight'

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I am creating two figures and writing to IO buffer object in python using flask and matplotlib `savefig` (I'm actually creating the figures with plotnine first). It errors out when using the `bbox_inches = 'tight'` parameter with errors like:

```
python(31535,0x70000b18f000) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7ff2051ac258: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0xbc0025000a007b04
```

I believe this is because it has to draw the figure twice (once to figure out the bbox size), and this messes with the size of the buffer object.  Also this only happens when I have more than one plot.  There is several pieces here, and I don't exactly know where the issue is.

I'm basically following this example, and it works when I don't include the `bbox_inches` parameter: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/canvasagg.html

Here is a reproducible example, with `app.py`:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import io
from plotnine import ggplot, geom_point, aes, stat_smooth, facet_wrap
from plotnine.data import mtcars
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template


def create_fig():
    p = (ggplot(mtcars, aes('wt', 'mpg', color='factor(gear)'))
    + geom_point()
    + stat_smooth(method='lm')
    + facet_wrap('~gear'))

    p = p.draw()

    figure = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)
    canvas.figure = p

    return figure


def create_fig2():
    p = (ggplot(mtcars, aes('wt', 'mpg', color='factor(gear)'))
    + geom_point()
    + stat_smooth(method='lm'))

    p = p.draw()

    figure = Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)
    canvas.figure = p

    return figure

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/gen_on_page')
def gen_on_page():
    figure = create_fig()
    fig_buffer = io.BytesIO()
  
    # this works:
    # figure.savefig(fig_buffer, format='png')
    # this breaks:
    figure.savefig(fig_buffer, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
    return Response(fig_buffer.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/gen_on_page2')
def gen_on_page2():
    figure = create_fig2()
    fig_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    
    # this works:
    # figure.savefig(fig_buffer, format='png')
    # this breaks:
    figure.savefig(fig_buffer, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
    return Response(fig_buffer.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

and index.html:

```html
<p>plots should be here..</p>
<img src="{{'gen_on_page'}}" alt="one plot">
<p></p>
<img src="{{'gen_on_page2'}}" alt="another plot">
```

Comment: its hard to tell without importing `plotnine`, but its likely that plotnine is plotting something that is far outside the axes, and that makes your figure abnormally large.

Comment: I don't think that is happening.. particularly because I can solve this by manually defining the bbox, slightly larger than the default size of 6.4 x 4.8: `bbox_inches=matplotlib.transforms.Bbox.from_extents(0,0,7,4.8)`

Comment: Bbox_inches=“tight” defines the bbox based on artists in your figure.  If one of them is far away from the origin, the new figure can be huge.